# Binding actions to a listbox in wxpython

Tags: python, listbox, wxpython

Using wxwidgets with python, how do I bind an event to the listbox so that everytime a new list box entry is clicked, information about the list box entry is displayed in the textbox?

Here is my code:

```
import wx
from ConfigParser import *
class settings(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Frame aka window', size=(500,500))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)

        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Field Type:", pos=(200,20))
        wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,"",pos=(270,20))    

        for msg_num in self.ACTIVE_MESSAGES:
            self.MESSAGE_FIELDS[msg_num] = configuration.get("MESSAGE_FIELDS", msg_num).replace(' ', '').split(',')
            self.MESSAGE_FIELD_TYPES[msg_num] = configuration.get("MESSAGE_TYPES", msg_num).replace(' ', '').split(',')

        cont=wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (20,20), (150,400),  self.MESSAGE_FIELDS['1'], wx.LB_SINGLE)
        cont.SetSelection(3)

if __name__=='__main__':
     app=wx.PySimpleApp()
     frame=settings(parent=None, id=-1)
     frame.Show()
     app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I came up with:

```
import wx
from ConfigParser import *
class settings(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Frame aka window', size=(500,500))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)




        configuration = ConfigParser()
        configuration.read('SerialReader.conf')
        self.ACTIVE_MESSAGES = configuration.get("GENERAL_SETTINGS", "ACTIVE_MESSAGES").split(',')


        self.fieldLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Field Type:", pos=(200,20))
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(panel,-1,"",pos=(270,20))    

        self.MESSAGE_FIELDS = {}
        self.MESSAGE_FIELD_TYPES = {}
        for msg_num in self.ACTIVE_MESSAGES:
            self.MESSAGE_FIELDS[msg_num] = configuration.get("MESSAGE_FIELDS", msg_num).replace(' ', '').split(',')
            self.MESSAGE_FIELD_TYPES[msg_num] = configuration.get("MESSAGE_TYPES", msg_num).replace(' ', '').split(',')

        cont=wx.ListBox(panel, 26, (20,20), (150,400),  self.MESSAGE_FIELDS['1'], wx.LB_SINGLE)
        cont.SetSelection(3)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.OnSelect, id = 26)

    def OnSelect(self, event):
        index = event.GetSelection()
        self.text.SetValue(self.MESSAGE_FIELD_TYPES['1'][index])




if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=settings(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```